# AWS Api Gateway with "/" in the URL Param

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

So I need to setup a url like this:

`/api/v1/doc/{id}`

Where id could be something like `10.10/M11`

If there any I can get around APIG and do a setup like this?

I tried this in `sam` already, it giving me 403

```
{
    "message": "Missing Authentication Token"
}
```

Comment: this may/may not work but may be try encoding the last part of the url as `10.10%2FM11`

Comment: I tried this already, still doesn't work, giving the same error

Comment: based on the document here at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-routes.html, you may want to try `{proxy+}`